# Focus kendo-grid when component is displayed

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I focus [kendo grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/) when my component (with grid) is loaded/shown/navigated? I want to [navigate](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/keyboard-navigation/) immediately after grid (my component) is displayed.

I tried with:

```
import { GridComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";

@ViewChild(GridComponent) public grid: GridComponent;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void
{
   this.grid.wrapper.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

But grid is not focused. Even my component is not, because event keypress is never triggered until I click one cell.

```
@HostListener("keyup", ["$event"])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent)
```

Comment: Can you navigate to the first cell of the grid instead?

Comment: I do not understand the question. I want that grid automatically has focus, so I can use my keyboard (for filtering, sorting, shortcuts, navigation ...) without the need to first activate (click) grid.

Comment: I just wondered if you could give the first cell of the grid an id, then focus that? But i'm unsure if this would work for the filtering and sorting shortcuts.

Comment: use jquery can make this work

Comment: No thank you. Using jQuery in Angular application would be 3 steps backward.